# how put a label inline in tkinter python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label

Im doing a pictures viewer in python ,
the code is this

```
def walk(dirname):
res = []
for name in os.listdir(dirname):
    path = os.path.join(dirname, name)      

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        res.append(path)
    else:
        walk(path)
return res


images = walk("images")

def show_image(filename):
  image = PIL.open(filename)
  image = image.resize((120, 120))
  photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
  label = Label(image=photo)
  label.image = photo
  label.pack()  

for i in images:
  show_image(i)
```

this code works but show the images in a block one above other, i want to show the labels inline something like in html

```
<div style="display:inline><img src="photo"></div>
```

how can achieved that?

Comment: by "inline", do you mean a single row rather than a single column?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the option `side="left"` to the pack command, images will all appear in a single row. Is that what you want?

```
label.pack(side="left")
```

For more information about the pack command, see here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm